# Perform Background Tasks in iOS

Tags: ios, background-process, background-task

I am trying to develop an **iOS application** where I need to perform most of the operations from background even after the app is terminated  in a particular time interval like fetching the below details and sending it to server.

- **HealthKit data**
- **Battery level**
- **Accelerometer data**

I found some solutions like **Background App Refresh** and **Silent push notification**. But which is a better solution for my need. Also please suggest if there is any other better approach to achieve it.

Comment: I think Accelerometer will not be allowed because it charges a lot of energy.

Comment: There is no guaranteed way of executing when the app is in the background, particularly if the user has terminated the app.  With background refresh, you cannot control the time at which the app runs.  You could use a silent push to trigger the app closer to a specific time, but again if the user has terminated the app then the push won't trigger the app to run in the background.

Comment: Rather than accelerometer use the GPS data to track the user

Answer (score 0):

This is all done in the background. You can consult this article for the latest changes in background tasks for iOS - [All about handling Background tasks in iOS 13](https://medium.com/swlh/handling-background-tasks-in-ios-13-67f717d94b3d)